# Проверка передаваемого значения в сеттере С++

Tags: c++, setter

Допустим, у меня есть такой сеттер. И всё ок, если я передам в него значение, которое пройдёт проверку. А если пользователь введёт, например, 301? Надо ведь тогда повторно переспросить, сообщить об ошибке. Но сеттер ничего не возвращает.

Не понимаю - как поставить условие для "переспрашивания" или дальнейшего выполнения кода?

```
void Player::SetAge(const int newAge)
{
    if (newAge < 0 || newAge > 300)
    return;

    age = newAge;
}
```

Comment: Возвращайте что-нибудь. `bool`, например. Или значение, которое теперь будет выставлено. Если всё хорошо - возвращайте `newAge`, иначе `age`.

Comment: Не заморачивайтесь, сделайте как вам проще. Можно проверять условие снаружи сеттера (в идеале вынести в отдельную функцию). Можно возвращать из сеттера true или false, смотря выполнилось условие или нет. Можно выбрасывать исключение, если число не подходит, и обрабатывать это исключение. Опробуйте разные варианты и посмотрите, какой вам нравится больше. Я бы использовал исключение.

Comment: Я утром напишу несколько вариантов, если не сложно, ответьте потом, какой выглядит лучше!

Comment: А сеттер может быть не войдовым? В гугле во всех примерах, на которые натыкалась в процессе поиска ответа, он именно такой. И нигде не нашла адекватного примера его реального применения в контексте проверок, в основном, описывается только сама конструкция. А насколько я поняла, то если он сводится к name = newName, его смысл теряется

Comment: @MariKa Сеттер - это просто придуманное название. С точки зрения языка это такой же метод (функция-член класса) как и все остальные. Так что возвращать из них можно что угодно.

Answer (score 2):

Можно возвращать bool, показывающий, успешно ли выполнено присваивание - это скорее сишный стиль, когда вместо исключений использовались коды возврата:

```
bool Player::SetAge(const int newAge)
{
  if (newAge < 0 || newAge > 300)
    return false;

  age = newAge;
  return true;
}
```

А можно кидать исключение - это стиль си++ и большинства современных языков:

```
void Player::SetAge(const int newAge)
{
  if (newAge < 0 || newAge > 300)
    throw std::invalid_argument("Age should be between 0 and 300 inclusive");

  age = newAge; 
}
```

Comment: Думаю  Abyx прав:  в таких функциях не совсем хорошо генерировать исключение.

Answer (score 2):

Текст ниже касается не только сеттеров но и их тоже. 
Здесь от логики вашего приложения зависит. Если по вашей задумке плохие параметры в сетер не будут передаваться никогда, но боитесь багов, стоит использовать assert.

```
void Player::SetAge(const int newAge)
{
    assert(newAge >= 0 && newAge <= 300);
    age = newAge;
}
```

При дебажной сборке, если условие нарушится, программа в этом месте упадёт, и через дебагер можно просмотреть что пошло не так. Удобно дебажить и тестить. 
В релизной сборке эта проверка игнорируется, что положительно сказывается на скорости.

Если же вы предполагаете, что данные могут быть не валидными и хотите корректно обрабатывать эту ситуацию есть 2 подхода. Первый - использовать код возврата.

```
int Player::SetAge(const int newAge)
{
    if (newAge < 0 || newAge > 300)
        return -1;

    age = newAge;
    return 1;
}
```

Вместо int, можно bool или что угодно другое использовать. Обычно используют int и для каждой причины ошибки свой номер. 
Второй - пробрасывать исключения.

```
void Player::SetAge(const int newAge)
{
    if (newAge < 0 || newAge > 300)
        throw std::runtime_error("error text");

    age = newAge;
}
```

Часто используют собственные исключения вместо стандартных.

Мешать в одном проэкте эти 2 подхода не стоит. 
Первый (код возврата) чуть быстрее работает, но, если есть ресурсы, которые нужно освобождать вручную (закрытие файла например, или освободить мьютекс), нужно писать это перед каждым return. Стоит такие классы не использовать (и даже если решили не через код возврата, а через исключения писать).
Исключения же немного удобнее. Во первых нет необходимости для каждой функции проверять код возврата. Типичный код на кодах возврата выглядит:

```
{
    шf (Foo1(...) != RESULT_OK ) {
        return (ERROR);
    }
    шf (Foo2(...) != RESULT_OK ) {
        return (ERROR);
    }
    шf (Foo3(...) != RESULT_OK ) {
        return (ERROR);
    }
    шf (Foo3(...) != RESULT_OK ) {
        return (ERROR);
    } 
    return RESULT_OK;
}
```

Во вторых во время дебага видно нормальную ошибку с нормальным текстом, поддерживается наследование и многое другое. 
Си не поддерживает исключения, там только коды вызврата. В плюсовом коде обычно практикуют писать через исключения. Stl написан через исключения. Коды возврата в плюсовом коде используют реже, но используют, в гугле, например.

Comment: Александреску любит приводить пример, когда можно использовать оба подхода - [Expected](https://youtu.be/CGwk3i1bGQI)

Comment: Исключения не во всех случая защитят вас от утечек ресурсов. Например, если память выделялась динамически, то при выходе функции по исключению эту память за вас никто не почистит. Другими словами, пользуясь исключениями, всегда нужно быть осторожным и понимать, что будет происходить при его генерации и какие ресурсы надо поместить в обёртки, использующие `RAII` (`std::lock_guard`, `std::shared_ptr` и т.д.)

Comment: Мои слова актуальны для уровня, когда ты точно понимаешь где и как освободить ресурсы, но ещё слабо проникся RAII. В случае кодов ошибок без raii не выжить вообще. Освобождение ресурсов нужно писать перед каждым return. Если ресурсы поменялись, везде нужно менять. Тоже видишь генератор багов. С Raii же жить вполне комфортно. В случае исключений, жить можно как с raii, так и без него, запихнув освобождение в блок final. Raii, хорошая и нужная вешь в любом случае, но сходу на этой идиоме писать не начнёшь.

Answer (score 0):

Сеттер должен сохранять значение, а не завершать программу, бросать исключение и т.п.

Делайте валидацию отдельно, в сеттере как максимум напишите `assert(IsValidAge(newAge));`

Comment: Случайно нажал не ту стрелочку:))))

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, ну так нажми на ту. Можно ж поменять.

Comment: @Abyx, а нафига тогда сеттер, если можно просто поле сделать доступным?

Comment: пока ответ не будет отредактирован, не получится

Comment: @Qwertiy, в основном согласен, но бывают ситуации, когда  целесообразно иметь закрытое поле и сеттер

Comment: А чем плохо бросать исключение?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, а чем хорошо занимать память и оставлять пользователью решать каждый раз, что нужно сделать, если он сам неправильное значение установил?  Это всего лишь сеттер...

Comment: @Abyx, плохо использовать исключения для неисключительных ситуаций. А чем не угодил цикл, я не понял. Если в нём устанавливается корректное значение и исключение не бросается, то почему функция с исключением должна быть медленнее? Ну помимо двух сравнений с допустимыми границами.

Answer (score 0):

Беззнаковый тип поможет проверять только одно условие, а дальше по вашему усмотрению:

```
void Player::SetAge(const unsigned newAge)
{
    if (newAge <= 300)  age = newAge;
    //в обратном случаи, если нужно, делаем что то
    //else some_function();         
}
```

Comment: Возраст в size_t? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy,  если  для автора вопроса int подходит, то чем мешает unsigned int?

Comment: Ничего. Но ты в ответе же написал не `unsigned`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, меньше букв в size_t,  который  и есть беззнаковое целое, хотя вы правы_лучше исправить...

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо! Почитав ваши ответы, пока остановилась на варианте такого типа:
сам метод

```
bool Rectangles::SetColor(int new_colorOfBackground)
{
   if (new_colorOfBackground >= 0 && new_colorOfBackground <= 16)
   {
       colorOfBackground = new_colorOfBackground;
       HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
       SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdOut, (WORD)((colorOfBackground << 4) | WHITE));
       return true;
    }
    else
   {
        cout << "Error. Number of color must be from 1 to 16." << endl;
        return false;
    }
```

}

мейн:

```
(int main()
{
   int new_colorOfBackground = 0;
   Rectangles R;
do  
{
    cout << "Choose the color (from 0 to 16): ";
    cin >> new_colorOfBackground;
}
while  (R.SetColor(new_colorOfBackground) == false);


//(...)

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```